# Migration From Datatable to Linq to Sql

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, datatable

In past I use dynamic sql and datatable to get data from database.

Such as :

```
Public shared function GetUsersByUsername(byval username as string) as datatable

dim strSQL as string="select * from

Users where Username= " & username

return dbClass.datatable(strSQL) 

end function
```

And I could use this data such this:

```
Dim Email as string = GetUsersByUsername("mavera").rows(0).items("email")`
```

or

```
datagrid1.datasource=GetUsersByUsername("mavera")

datagrid1.databind()
```

And now, I want to use linq to sql to do that. I can write query with linq, but I can't use it like a datatable. What should my new using be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get rid of GetUsersByName() altogether, because you can do it in one line.  You will also have to change *how* you get things like the user's email.  So GetUsersByName() would be rewritten something like:

```
dc.Users.Where(Function(u) u.Username = username);
```

and your email assignment statement would be written as:

```
Dim Email as string = users.First().Email;
```

Forgive me if my VB syntax is off.  I never use it anymore...